# jQuery range slider - any event other than slidestart and slidestop

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

I can read slidestart and slidestop events. However what I want is an event in between. Basically if I pull or swipe the slider to the right then I would like to know what the current value is (on an ongoing basis) so that I could display that value in another DOM Object that converts and displays second in HH:MM:SS format.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI slider?

Comment: There's something called [jQuery Range Slider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html) and a few others that this could be as well ?

Comment: I am using JQuery Mobile range slider